# Server2Go like for ASP.NET , A portable ASP.NET Server

Tags: asp.net, iis, portability, server2go

Server2Go is easily run  Web server that supports Apache, PHP, MySQL, and Perl right from a USB flash drive. You can use Server2Go right out of the box without any installation.
For example, imagine being able to carry a live Web site demo into a sales pitch meeting. 
Is there something like it for ASP.NET ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [CassiniDev](http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/).
I am using it happily for a long time without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Cassini is one.

This is the original:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dmitryr/archive/2008/10/03/cassini-for-framework-3-5.aspx

This one has been modified: http://ultidev.com/products/cassini/

For the MSSQL - you can use SQL Compact Edition.

Comment: is not http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/ more current?

Comment: ok. i was actually asking you a doubt :)